# Game hangs on multiple runs

Tags: android, lua, freeze

I have created a game in lua. Everthing worked good on corona Simulator.
But when I compiled the game and installed the .apk file on my phone, the game began to hang.
It was like, when I played multiple times without closing the game, it began to hang after like 3rd or 4th run. 
When I closed the game, it worked normal again for first 3-4 runs, but then again begin to hang.

What could be the possible issues?
Anyone who could help me with this, please?

Comment: No one can help me regarding this issue?PLEASE?

Answer (score 0):

Check your codes thoroughly, memory leaks might have been causing this. Make sure to nil out anything that you don't need (objects, images, timers, etc). Just store the one you need in like myData.lua or in a database.